# Check a string for 2 values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string, for example: `dashboard/12398911/overzicht` and I want to check that string for 2 values. For `dashboard` and `overzicht`. If the first check is false, then the second check doesn't need to happen.

This is my current code:

```
private pageTypes = ['dashboard', 'klantenkaart', 'complexkaart', 'objectkaart', 'collegakaart'];
private subTypes = ['overzicht', 'tijdlijn', 'contracten', 'financieel', 'mededelingen'];

private isOnPageWithFilter(currentUrl: string): boolean {
    for (const pageType of this.pageTypes) {
        if (currentUrl.includes(pageType)) {
            for (const subType of this.subTypes) {
                if (currentUrl.includes(subType)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way of doing this where I don't need a nested for loop.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/FXhbCr9aaXcL61g3q7Fe?p=preview

Comment: split your string using the delimiter `/` then check the index 0 and the index 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify it by using [Array.prototype.some](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method and lazy evaluation of `&&` operator

````
const pageTypes = ['dashboard', 'klantenkaart', 'complexkaart', 'objectkaart', 'collegakaart'];
const subTypes = ['overzicht', 'tijdlijn', 'contracten', 'financieel', 'mededelingen'];

function isOnPageWithFilter(currentUrl) {
    return pageTypes.some(x => currentUrl.includes(x)) && subTypes.some(x => currentUrl.includes(x));
}

console.log(isOnPageWithFilter('foobar.com?dashboard')); // false
console.log(isOnPageWithFilter('foobar.com?dashboard&overzicht')); // true

```
````

Comment: Wouldn't this return `true` for `eenfinancieelramp#onwilligeklantenkaartoon`? (How do I check *lazy evaluation*?)

Comment: In JavaScript (and many other languages) logical operators (&&,||) are evaluated lazily. This means that if first part of expression `a && b`, that is `a`, is evaluated to false then whole expression is false and there is no need to evaluate `b`